# React native Text input scroll issue

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput

I am new to react native, I want to make a text input which accepts 3 lines of data and after that, it should automatically get the scroll up.

I got stuck and need help to resolve this issue.

Suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 1):

You have to add some properties to that field such that

1) numberOfLines
2) multiline